# JBoss CLI escaping SELECT 1

Tags: postgresql, jboss, jboss-cli

Using JBoss (EAP 6.4) CLI to deploy, and at this point, want to add a datasource.

The cli command is like this

```
/profile=XXX/subsystem=datasources/data-source=XXX:add\(connection-url=XXX,url-delimiter="|",jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/XXX,driver-name=postgresql,user-name=XXX,password=XXX,check-valid-connection-sql="SELECT 1",validate-on-match=true,background-validation=false,share-prepared-statements=false\)
```

The exact `add` call looks this:

```
/data-source=${DS_NAME}:add(                     \
      connection-url=${DS_CONNECTION_URL},           \
      jndi-name=${DS_JNDI_NAME},                     \
      driver-name=${DS_DRIVER_NAME},                 \
      user-name=${DB_USER},                          \
      password=${DB_USER_PASSWD},                    \
      check-valid-connection-sql=\"SELECT 1\",       \
      validate-on-match=true,                        \
      background-validation=false,                   \
      share-prepared-statements=false)
```

Actually only this part is interesting

```
check-valid-connection-sql="SELECT 1"
```

After a successfull deployment, the whitespace will be replace with a double apostrophe.
This is what I get in the pgsql log:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "1" at character 9
STATEMENT: SELECT''1
```

The JBoss admin console also shows `SELECT''1` in the Configuration -> Datasources -> Validation > Check Valid Sql attribute

Tried to escape it properly several ways, without success. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed to share the result yet, so:

JBoss EAP had a bug with the whitespaces, before version 7.1.2.Final (EAP)
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-4263

Answer (score 0):

You can define the datasource using the `data-source add` command, specifying the appropriate argument values.

Domain mode:

```
data-source add --profile=<default | ha | full | full-ha> --name=<Resource ID> --connection-url=<Connection URL> --jndi-name=<JNDI Name> --driver-name=<Driver Name>
```

Standalone mode:

```
data-source add --name=<Resource ID> --connection-url=<Connection URL> --jndi-name=<JNDI Name> --driver-name=<Driver Name>
```

A working example:

```sh
data-source add \
    --name=TEST \
    --check-valid-connection-sql="Select 1" \
    --driver-name=h2 --jndi-name=java:jboss/test \
    --connection-url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

To get a list of the available options:

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] data-source add --help
```

Comment: Thanks for it, but the setup is looks ok and works! The only problem is with the whitespace escaping for some reason. I've added my exact call of the add method to the description.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your standalone(-*).xml or domain(-*).xml to configure a datasource:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.2">
    <datasources>
      <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/OracleDS" pool-name="OracleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhostname:1521:oracle</connection-url>
        <driver>oracle</driver>
        <pool>
          <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
          <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
          <prefill>true</prefill>
        </pool>
        <security>
          <user-name>myuser</user-name>
          <password>mypass</password>
        </security>
        <validation>
          <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
          <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
          <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"></exception-sorter>
        </validation>
      </datasource>
      <drivers>
        <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.jdbc">
          <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
      </drivers>
    </datasources>
  </subsystem>
```

Comment: Yep, it's correct, but my problem is not being able to set the proper value during the deployment process. It's not an option to edit the config files every time when a new deployment happens.